# Bounded Priority Queue Inheritance vs Composition

Tags: java, oop

I want to write a Bounded Priority Queue class. This is essentially a priority queue but has a bound on the number of elements that can be there in the queue. So, if I insert a new element and the queue is full, then I see if the element is greater than the top of the queue. If yes, then I discard the new element. If no, then I remove the top element and insert this new element (and the queue gets automatically reorganized). I have currently implemented BoundedPriorityQueue as derived from PriorityQueue having a "maxCount" member and I have overridden the add method and added the functionality I described above. I am wondering if I should consider doing it the composition way rather than the inheritance way. My current approach seems simple though.

If I were to go for composition, then I have to derive from the AbstractQueue class, implement the methods and then compose the priority queue with it.

Thanks,

Venk

Comment: Is there some reason you don't like your current solution? Is it overly complex? Is it hard to understand? Is it too slow or prone to race conditions?

Comment: well, none of it. But in Effective Java, Joshua came across a slightly different but related problem but solved it using composition. I am trying to explore the reason behind it.

Comment: If you use inheritance you have to ask yourself if you could substitute a Priority Queue with a BoundedPriorityQueue without facing any problems. If yes use inheritance, otherwise composition. If in doubt, use composition.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion it is better to use composition. because, inheritance this way is the violation of [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). derived types shouldn't replace base types' functionality.
this link will be useful: [prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with inheritance in the described case - it's a typical example. You can (as I do when I cannot decide between multiple implementations) create both solutions, try them out, see how they look API wise, performance, implementation and comprehension wise, and decide based on that.